# Array con posiciones dinámicas en php

Tags: php, php5

¿Hay alguna manera de asignar dinámicamente las claves de un array en `php`?

Por ejemplo, tengo un array que puede variar de una posición a n posiciones. Con ese array, ¿Cómo podría definir el número de posiciones que tiene?

Ejemplo:

```
$arrCampos = array("Campo1", "Campo2", ... "CampoN");
$array["Campo1"]["Campo2"] ... ["CampoN"] = 1;
```

Comment: De donde provienen las llaves de tu arreglo, por poner un ejemplo?

Comment: Las posiciones vendrian de unos filtros dinamicos. Un formulario que contiene varios checkbox, que son configurables

Comment: Por como planteas la pregunta me parece entender que quieres saber su tamaño final, para lo que se usaría **count( $arr )** o bien las llaves que tiene, función: **array_keys( $arr )** que devuelve un array con las llaves.

Comment: utiliza un foreach y ya, por cada vuelta el se posiciona en un elemento y lo puedes trabajar

Comment: No me queda clara la pregunta. Como tal, los arrays en PHP son dinámicos. Si son asociativos, puedes definir tu la clave con algo como $arr["clave1"] = "valor"; si no defines la clave, se genera automáticamente como un contador incremental

Comment: La pregunta no es nada clara.

Answer (score 0):

Una opcion, seria establecer la variable en una cadena y luego con la funcion eval de php, para evaluar la cadena como codigo.

[Ejemplo](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/476988/create-multidimensional-array-from-array-of-keys-and-a-value)

```
$keys = array('key1', 'key2', 'key3');
$value = 'some value';
$string='$md';
foreach($keys as $index => $key){   
    $string.="['$key']";
}
$string.= '=$value;';
eval($string);
var_dump($md);
```

Comment: No creo que sea lo que pregunta, además, usar eval() es desaconsejable.

Answer (score 0):

No se si es esto a lo que te refieres. Pero la forma que uso yo para crear arrays dinámicos en `php` es la siguiente:

```
<?php 
$array = array();
for ($a = 0; $a < 100; $a++)
{
    $clave = "A_" . $a;
    $valor = "B_" . $a;
    $array[$clave] = $valor;
}
?>
```